# Android libgdx local file writing doesn't work

Tags: android, libgdx, local-storage

I have implemented local filehandle in libgdx to write to a text file. It saves to the desktop correctly, but the same doesn't work for android? Am I missing something? This is the code I have... the data is saved to desktop and file is created too.

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("lightTest.txt");

ArrayList<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(timeKeeper.keySet());  
for (Integer i: keys)
{
    file.writeString("LightTest: \n" + i + " \t" + timeKeeper.get(i) + "\n", true);
}
```

What am I missing for android? Do I need to add something on the android side?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Are you getting an exception?  (Please include that if so.)  Are you reading the file and not getting data back?  Please include that code if so.

Comment: Oh the text file isn't being saved at all. I want the text file saved so I can add it to parse.com. One the data is collected, which is stored in a hashmap timeKeeper, I want to save it to a text file. When I run the desktop main class, it saves it, but when I run the android MainActivity, it run the app correctly, doesn't save the text file.

Comment: Where/how are you checking the file to see if it was saved or not?

Comment: I am trying to access it so I can upload it to parse.com. Somebody said it's saved in data/data/packagename directory and remains not visible directly. So I assume I should be able to access it in the MainAcitvity by calling filehandle again and save it to parse.com?

Comment: Correct, the file is saved in the private area of the application which is not generally accessible to other applications.  You should be able to re-read the file's contents later.

Comment: Ah how would I go about saving the file in Parse.com. Wouldn't I have to use REST API in libgdx and now even worry about MainActivity in the android since data have to saved before.

Comment: please ask a new question with new details about what you have tried and what did not work.

Comment: Hey, I posted the question. Please help me. Thanks. This is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748678/libgdx-parse-com-save-text-file